# google maps with a SlidingUpPanelLayout appear a strange line

Tags: android, google-maps, slider

I have a **google maps and a SlidingUpPanelLayout** that i swipe from button to top everything work fine except that i have a line on the layout slide like image show, i circle the line that make me crazy

[image: line circled]

[image]

The main layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fr.****.SlidingUpPanelLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:shadowHeight="4dp"
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
sothree:overlay="true">

 ...

  <include

     android:divider="@null"
     android:dividerHeight="0dp"
     layout="@layout/f_restaurant_info_screen" />

   </fr.****.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

the included f_restaurant_info_screen.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:id="@+id/panel_root">

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:focusable="true"`
      android:background="@color/fiche_resto_background">

   ....
```

> Problem is map consist of line that i want to remove

Thanks for your help

Simply sothree:shadowHeight="0dp" resolve the problem

Comment: add `SlidingUpPanelLayout` layout

Comment: deleting this shadowHeight doesn't work, but when i put sothree:shadowHeight="0dp" its work so thanks for yout help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this sothree:shadowHeight="4dp" to this

sothree:shadowHeight="0dp"